# How to wrap emails in the respective cell itself without extending to another row?

Tags: reactjs, semantic-ui-react

[image: Snap]

HI, I'm new to reactjs, my objective is to wrap the emails which are placed in `Members` field as similar to the `Qualification & experience`  as shown in snapshot for reference. Can anyone help me in wrapping the emails in **Members** field without exceeding towards `Action` field.

```
<Table>
            <Table.Header>
              <Table.Row>

                <Table.HeaderCell>Group Name</Table.HeaderCell>
                <Table.HeaderCell>Members</Table.HeaderCell>
                <Table.HeaderCell>Action</Table.HeaderCell>
              </Table.Row>
            </Table.Header>
            <Table.Body>

                <Table.Row >

                  <Table.Cell>Group 1</Table.Cell>
                  <Table.Cell >abc@yahoo.com, def@gmail.com, xyz@hotmail.com</Table.Cell>
                   <Table.Cell>
                    <Button variant="info">Edit</Button>
                    &nbsp;<Button variant="danger">Delete</Button>
                  </Table.Cell> 
                </Table.Row>
            </Table.Body>
          </Table>
```

[Here is the sample code](https://codesandbox.io/s/charming-sun-bchh8)

Can anyone help me in this query to wrap emails in members field without exceeding towards `Actions` field.

Comment: seems to be this is not react only, but also you use specific ui library. Please specify its tag

Comment: @AlexNikonov -  Hi, Yes i'm using Semantic-ui-react for designing purpose in reactjs components

Answer (score 0):

This can be achieved by having such a method responsible for emails rendering in the `<Group>` component:

```
renderEmails(emails) {
    return emails.map((email) => <div key={email}>{email}</div>);
}
```

Wrapping every email in a separate `<div>` allows displaying it in a new line.

And then just use it in `<Group>` component's render method like this:

```
<Table.Cell>
    {this.renderEmails(['abc@yahoo.com', 'def@gmail.com', 'xyz@hotmail.com'])}
</Table.Cell>
```

Please take a look at [your edited sample](https://codesandbox.io/s/boring-monad-486o2?file=/src/components/group.jsx).

Comment: Hi, I've updated my query with JSON data, Can you please assist me how to implement it by seeing my JSON data

Answer (score 0):

If you set the `width` or `max-width` styles of your table cells (well, technically of the `<td`> elements they generate), their contents will wrap automatically.

No need to "reinvent the wheel" here: the browser will do everything you want for you, IF you tell it when to start wrapping ... ie. by defining the widths of the columns of your table.

Comment: @Hi, can you help me, how to keep max-width, i mean it should accept only 2 emails in a row.

Comment: I don't mean this to be offensive in any way, but ... when you're building a house, and you have to ask someone how to cement two bricks together, you're probably trying to tackle a project that exceeds your abilities.  Similarly here, if you're building something with React, and you don't know how to use CSS, you really need to go back and (re-)learn the basics of web development first, before trying to learn React.  a great resource for this is: https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Learn

Comment: That being said, here's a code snippet to point you in the right direction: `<Table.Cell style={{maxWidth: '10em'}}>`.  That won't limit a cell to "2 emails" ... because it's impossible to limit anything to "2 emails" (because "2 emails" isn't a unit of measurement in web development).  What it will do is limit the column to `10em`, or approximately 10 characters in length.  You can adjust that number to whatever size you feel is "2 emails worth" (or you can use `200px` or any other valid CSS unit of measurement). Good luck!

Comment: I apologize for asking but i've tried early giving css but it didn't worked that's the only reason i asked query based on functionality not for css things.. i could see your answer so thought of asking again, may be any other way to solve this prob.

Comment: First off, no need to apologize!  Second it seems the library you are using doesn't let you provide custom styles (which you can do with a normal/lower-case `<td>` in React). See: https://react.semantic-ui.com/collections/table/ (and note the lack of a `style` prop for `Table.Cell`).  You could file an issue and ask the library to allow custom styles, but I noticed that the component *does* have a `width` prop.  I'd try playing with that prop, as it seems to do something similar ...  just understand you're using a 3rd party tool and it works however they want; not like a normal React `td`.

Comment: Yes absolutely true, But we can override the styles, by giving `!important` for our specific stylings :).

Comment: Oh, that's an option I didn't even think to suggest! Absolutely: another way around your library's limits would be to use a separate (outside your React app) style.  I still think you might want to play around with that `width` prop first, to see if it can do what you need it to do, but if not then using separate styles to limit your column width should work too.